# SSRS and Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, web-parts

Well I am doing development in Sharepoint 2007 and SSRS 2008. I am pretty new to both of the technologies. What I am trying to do is I have created a report in SSRS and using Report Viewer Web Part to show it in my Sharepoint Web site. But I am strucked with passing parameter to my report from another web part that implements (IWebPartField).

Please help me out.

Kind Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 2):

Store the User Input in a variable and pass the input to the report as Query String. You could create a "Run Report Button" which sets the Report Viewer Web Part URL to point at your Report and use the user input in the ReportURL and SSRS will detect the parameters:

I.e.

```
ReportViewerWebPart.ReportURL = "http://yoursharepointwebsite/Reports/YourReport.aspx?Id=1&ReportParam1=UserInputField&ReportParam2=UserInputField2
```